# Invocar error do ajax

Tags: php, ajax

Estou usando, para mostrar que está carregando enquanto envio o cliente para o web service via php

```js
//Tipo do método
            type: "POST",
            url: "../Processos/AcCadasCliente.php",
            data: $('#formulario').serialize(), 
                beforeSend: function () {
                    // enquanto a função esta sendo processada,
                    // a mensagem "Carregando"
                    $('#enviar').html('.....');
                },
                //Quando terminado a função
                success: function (txt) {
                    //Se deu certo, mostrar mensagem, enviado com sucesso
                    $('#enviar').html('.....');
                },
                //Em caso de erro
                error: function (txt) {
                  $('#enviar').html('Erro');
                }
```

Acontece que mesmo sem eu ter conexão com o web service, ainda sim, só executa o beforesend e o sucess.
Como invocar o erro do ajax

Comment: Tens a certeza que o web service não está acessível? Se não tem ligação devia dar erro. Achas que consegues reproduzir o erro aqui -> http://jsfiddle.net/oxu8ux6m/?

Comment: Tenho sim, no código php ele entra no cath, mas fica só nisso, ele não vai para o erro ajax

Comment: `no código php ele entra no catch` Então ele está conseguindo se conectar com o servidor, ou seja, a requisição não está com problemas e a função `success` sempre será chamada.

Comment: Não tem erro não requisição, mas tem erro na resposta pois não está conectado com web service, e era esse erro que eu queria chamar o error do javascript

Answer (score 0):

O ideal é você gerenciar o status da requisição com o php, pode usar assim:

```
if ($tudo_ok)
    {
        header('Content-Type: application/json');
        print json_encode($result);
    }
else
    {
        header('HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server');
        header('Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8');
        die(json_encode(array('message' => 'ERROR', 'code' => 1337)));
    }
```

Comment: Não aparece nada na tela.

Comment: Você nao deve ter entendido o que ele quis dizer. Só copiar e colar a resposta nao vai funcionar. No php vc tem que tratar o erro de conexao com o webservice  e printar algo para que a funcao success do javascript trate o erro